# Making a query and adding the result to a struct with Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

Based on SQLite tutorial for Swift ([Link](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#selecting-rows)), I am able to perform a query successfully as follows (with a raw query):

```
struct myStruct {
   var value1 = String()
   var value2 = String()
   var value3 = String()
   var value4 = String()
}

do {
   guard let queryResults = try? db.prepare("SELECT value1, value2, value3, value4 FROM table WHERE identifier = 0")
   else {
      print("ERROR")
      return
   }
   //first way to get data (works)
   for row in queryResults {
      let data = myStruct(value1: row[0] as! String, value2: row[1] as! String, value3: "", eventDate: row[2] as! String, value4: row[3] as! String)
      tableViewData.append(data)
   }
   //second way to get data into struct     
   _ = queryResults.map { row in
       let data = myStruct(value1: row[0]! as! String, value2: row[1] as! String, value3: "", eventDate: row[2] as! String, value4: row[3] as! String)
       tableViewData.append(data)
   }
}
catch let ex {
   print("ReadDB error: \(ex)")
}
```

But, if I change the style of the query as follows:

```
do {
   let query = myTable.select(value1, value2, value3, value4).where(identifier == 0)
   guard let queryResults = try? db.prepare(query)
   else {
      print("ERROR")
      return
   }
   //does not work
   for row in queryResults {
      let data = myStruct(value1: row[0] as! String, value2: row[1] as! String, value3: "", eventDate: row[2] as! String, value4: row[3] as! String)
      tableViewData.append(data)
   }
   //neither working   
   _ = queryResults.map { row in
       let data = myStruct(value1: row[0]! as! String, value2: row[1] as! String, value3: "", eventDate: row[2] as! String, value4: row[3] as! String)
       tableViewData.append(data)
   }
}
catch let ex {
   print("ReadDB error: \(ex)")
}
```

I get this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'Row' with an index of type 'Int'

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you provide link for tutorial?

Comment: Sure... https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#selecting-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right way

```
do {
   let query = myTable.select(value1, value2, value3, value4).where(identifier == 0)
   guard let queryResults = try? db.prepare(query)
   else {
      print("ERROR")
      return
   }
   //option 1
   for row in queryResults {
      let data = myStruct(value1: try row.get(value1), value2: try row.get(value2), value3: try row.get(value3), value4: try row.get(value4))
      tableViewData.append(data)
   }
   //option 2  
   _ = queryResults.map { row in
       let data = myStruct(value1: try row.get(value1), value2: try row.get(value2), value3: try row.get(value3), value4: try row.get(value4))
       tableViewData.append(data)
   }
}
catch let ex {
   print("ReadDB error: \(ex)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the tutorial, it seems that something like

```
//This is from tutorial

let query = users.select(email)           // SELECT "email" FROM "users"
             .filter(name != nil)     // WHERE "name" IS NOT NULL
             .order(email.desc, name) // ORDER BY "email" DESC, "name"
             .limit(5, offset: 1)     // LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1
```

That `.select(item)` actually IS the query itself. So, whenever you do

`let query = myTable.select(value1, value2, value3, value4).where(identifier == 0)` then THIS is the query; you don't need to prepare anything for the db. The person(s) who created this library has tried to make it easier whereas you can just do `.select(item)` instead of creating a statement and sending it to a db.

Using the example above, you can see that the query selects email, where it is filtered, ordered, and limited. Therefore, for you, `query` is what you want as `queryResult` -- I am not sure what that would return... You would be running the result of `query` on `db.prepare(query)`...hrm? :P